# No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am attempting to build a brand new Spring Framework 4.0 project without all of the magical gradle stuff, but simply kicking it old school.

I am following the tutorial here: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/ and am having some success. I'm simply stuck at this point.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.corrisoft.air.db.integration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.corrisoft.air.db.JPAConfiguration;

import static com.corrisoft.air.db.fixture.JPAAssertions.assertTableExists;
import static com.corrisoft.air.db.fixture.JPAAssertions.assertTableHasColumn;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JPAConfiguration.class })
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class PersonMappingIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager manager;

    @Test
    public void thatItemCustomMappingWorks() throws Exception {
        assertTableExists(manager, "PERSONS");

        assertTableHasColumn(manager, "PERSONS", "FIRST_NAME");
        assertTableHasColumn(manager, "PERSONS", "LAST_NAME");
    }
}
```

When I run this unit test, I get the following stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@68c884e] to prepare test instance [com.corrisoft.air.db.integration.PersonMappingIntegrationTests@7448bc3d]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.corrisoft.air.db.integration.PersonMappingIntegrationTests': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.persistence.EntityManager com.corrisoft.air.db.integration.PersonMappingIntegrationTests.manager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:326)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.persistence.EntityManager com.corrisoft.air.db.integration.PersonMappingIntegrationTests.manager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
```

Based on observations followed by research, it would appear that it's telling me that there are two EntityManager classes. The first one is from the hibernate JPA jar, but can't find the second one. It would appear to be telling me it's in Spring ORM, but there's no definition within that class.

Here is the JPAConfiguration class being used in the test:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.corrisoft.air.db;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.corrisoft.air.db.repository.PersonsRepository;

/**
 * @author Corrisoft Android Development
 * 
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.corrisoft.db.repository", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = { PersonsRepository.class }, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.corrisoft.air.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the error message is telling you that you've defined multiple *beans* that implement `EntityManager`, and we need to see your configurations in order to identify where.

Comment: @chrylis Hmmm...I did a search for EntityManager in my project and found only some places where it's being returned in JPAConfiguration which is almost perfectly copied from the tutorial. What other config do you need to see?

Comment: @chrylis I'm a little lost since and am following the tutorial on faith hoping that it will make sense when complete.

Comment: Post that `JPAConfiguration` class. If you found **places** where `EntityManager` is being returned, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Try removing the `entityManager` bean. I think Spring is now smart enough (especially with `@EnableJpaRepositories`) to create EMs as necessary from the factory.

Comment: I also hadn't been thinking quite clearly. An `EntityManager` object is transaction-scoped, and it's inappropriate to expose it as (at least) a singleton bean. Correct answer below.

Comment: Indeed I found there are quite some mistakes in that spring.io guide series, for example, for the second section of its DATA tutorial, the sequence of invoking the extension of CrudRepository is mentioned in the later part but used before, which blocks me for quite a while.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `EntityManager` interface belongs to JPA and is implemented by JPA providers (such as Eclipse), not Spring, and it has its own injection annotation: `@PersistenceContext`. `EntityManager` objects are transaction-scoped and should not be exposed as beans as you're doing. Instead, either use the JPA annotation to inject the `EntityManager`:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

or, since it looks like you're trying to use Spring repositories, inject the repository instead:

```
@Autowired
PersonRepository pr;
```

Comment: So, it's a bug in the tutorial. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: The second option of autowiring respository worked for me

Answer (score 10):

though this article is pretty old and has already bean answered, i encountered the same problem with the oficial turorial spring-data-jpa on spring-io website.

the current spring data jpa example/spring io guide detects at least 2 beans implementing the interface "EntityManager". You must help spring what implementation to wire to. I recommend to add a qualifier.

In class JPAConfiguration add:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier(value = "entityManager")
public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

In the test class add:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "entityManager")
EntityManager manager;
```

Hope it helps you.

I would not necessarily use the "PersistenceContext", as spring handles the creation of transaction manager, entitymanager, beans, datasource etc.. 
"PersisenceConetext" annotation is basically defined for container managed entityfactory of an application server/ejb compliant container

Comment: I had trouble with `@Transactional` scope and this solution, using `@PersistentContext` injected the right `EntityManager` instance (`SharedEntityManagerBean`). The `JpaTransactionManager` didn't closed the Session (nor flushed it) after the `@Transactional` method ended. Had this problem with multiple transactions managers and multiple datasources only.