# No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, orm, javabeans, entitymanager

I have this problem...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I don't usually boot. these are configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringOrmConfig {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public SpringOrmConfig(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean(@Autowired Properties jpaProperties) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("jpa-unit");
    emFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean");
    emFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("factoryBean");
    emFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    emFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("my.package");
    emFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return emFactoryBean;
}
...
```

The problem occurs in this class

```
@Repository
public class MyRepoSpringOrmImpl extends AbstractSpringOrm<Group> implements MyRepo {

    @Autowired
    protected MyRepoSpringOrmImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super(em, My.class);
    }
...
```

configuration

```
@ComponentScan("my.package")
@PropertySource("classpath:db_config.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${driver}")
    String driver;
    @Value("${url}")
    String url;
    @Value("${login}")
    String login;
    @Value("${password}")
    String password;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(driver);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUser(login);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I do not understand what's the matter... Help please

p.s. I deliberately didn't use Spring Boot because it's not allowed in my project

Comment: What is the version of `spring` you use?

Comment: I have the same problem( and i have no solution

Comment: @HarryCoder and have dependencies: spring-context, spring-webmvc, spring-aop, spring-orm, spring-tx. with version 5.2.19.RELEASE.

Comment: @HarryCoder updated to 5.3.15. same problem

Comment: Just simply use Spring Boot and Spring Data. You don't have to manage your entity manager this way

Comment: @HarryCoder Good advice. I understand that using boot will be easier. But you can't use spring boot in my project

Comment: Will I be able to configure without boot?

Comment: could you please show DataSource  bean too? when you use @Qualifier destination bean have to has @Component("bean_name")

Comment: @DaniyalVaghar added the configuration to the question description. Can I show you something else?

Comment: you can refer this  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301426/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-persistence-entitymanager

Comment: @HydrogenUranium I've read this question and answers before. But I have another problem.

Comment: @IlyaY OK.well.you should define your bean like this:@Bean(name = "dataSource"), see is it solve your problem

Comment: @DaniyalVaghar unfortunately not (

Comment: i saw an example that used @Qualifier("dataSource") above the @Bean.you can try this too

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/javaconfig-methods-inter-dependency.html